# Using namespaces in PHP :: Fatal Error Core\App not found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, namespaces, fatal-error, classnotfound

I made an MVC project in local (WAMP) and it runs perfectly. But when i deploy it in a web server apears this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Core\App' not found in home/dmlink/public_html/public/index.php on line 14
```

This is the code of the line 14:

```
13: spl_autoload_register('autoload_classes');
14: $app = new \Core\App;
15: $app->render();
```

The structure of the project:

- app : Here are the controllers, models, and views.
- core: Here are the core files.
- public: Since this directory runs the app.

I got the same version in the web server like in localhost:

- php 5.5
- apache 2.4

This is the complete code of index:

```
define('PROJECT_PATH', dirname(__DIR__));
define('APP_PATH', PROJECT_PATH . '/app');

function autoload_classes($class_name){
    $file = PROJECT_PATH . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    if (is_file($file)) {
        include_once $file;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_classes');
$app = new \Core\App;
$app->render();
```

Any idea that is causing this error
ThankS for all by the way.

Comment: Are you using composer? If not, it allows you to autoload your classes and download any other dependancies and autoload them as well.

Comment: I use a slp_autoload_register() to load all the classes that are in the Core folder.

Comment: Have you registered/included the path to the core files? Check phpinfo just in case? Else try restart server.

Comment: I added the path to the php.ini file, and in the .htaccess file (php_value inlcude_path) and i try to set the path by adding on set_include_path() function but doesnt work

Comment: If you have checked that the file is actually included on both servers, then it must be a configurational difference between the servers. Check your apache and php.ini settings. Are both servers allowing file include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the error, and was very simple!.

The error was the name of the directories where the classes are.
I just rename the directory 'Core' instead 'core' .... And thats it.

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error lies in the server configuration, check your server config file and make sure you have the correct path to your MVC project.

Comment: I reviewed the configuration file again, and the path is the correct. : (

Comment: I have faced this kind of error and the error solely lies in the server config file. Be sure to check again properly especially the location to php.

Comment: I added the path to the php.ini file, and in the .htaccess file (php_value inlcude_path) and i try to set the path by adding on set_include_path() function but doesnt work